# How often is it okay to use Automapper's Mapper.CreateMap?

Tags: .net, automapper

I inherited a code base from another developer group that uses Automapper's mapping capabilities.  The application is a .NET MVC web application and I see the Mapper.CreateMap statements sprinkled throughout controllers / helpers / etc.  Sometimes, the mappings are completely the same (i.e., I see `Mapper.CreateMap<Product, ProductViewModel>()` in multiple places) but in others, sometimes there are ignore statements (`Mapper.CreateMap<Product, ProductViewModel>().ForMember(f => f.Regions, opt => opt.Ignore()`)

Is it bad practice to have these static calls being used over and over again?  I'd like to think I could do it in a class elsewhere, but some methods require some different setups depending on the method.

Answer (score 2):

I don't call Mapper.CreateMap - it gets confusing with all that configuration spread out everywhere.

Instead I call Mapper.Initialize, put it in one place and have it called once per AppDomain. There's not a huge performance penalty in calling CreateMap all over the place - it's just a big ugly.